# Non inverting op amp issue

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

[image][image]

I'm using an lm3900 quad op amp to run a smart phone audio signal to a bs170 MOSFET. When I use the inverting configuration it works well, but when I use the same resistor values (1k and 10k) with the non inverting configuration it either doesn't work or the output is too low. Is there an impedance issue that I'm not aware of between these 2 configurations or does it seem like a faulty chip? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include you entire circuit, and what you intend to do. Are you measuring the output after the mosfet or before. My guess is the driving signal to the mosfet is the problem. You have also not shown how your biasing the mosfet or the gain you have on the mosfet. Why do you have the mosfet anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there an impedance issue that I'm not aware of

There is a difference in input impedance between the two circuits.

The input impedance of the non-inverting configuration is essentially the input impedance of the op-amp itself; that is, very high.

The input impedance of the inverting configuration is very close to \$R_{in}\$, because the summing node (negative input terminal of the op-amp) is a virtual ground. Another way to look at this is that the feedback will try to operate so that the input current is \$V_{in}/R_{in}\$ and your signal source will need to be able to supply this current.

**But**

But that is probably not your problem. Notice that the LM3900 does not have a typical op-amp input stage:

[image]

With those base-emitter junctions from the inputs to ground, you really need to operate this amplifier with the input terminals held near ground. Your non-inverting amplifier circuit doesn't do that, so it's not likely to work well.

Comment: I found an app note giving more info on using the LM3900 [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa653/snoa653.pdf).

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks for that. Makes sense to me. I'll look into the details of this chip.

Answer (score 1):

The LM3900 is very unlike nearly all other op-amps.  The OP schematic for the non-inverting amplifier *can't_possibly* work correctly (if at all) with a '3900 because you can't apply a voltage to either input...only a current.   To make the non-inverting amp work, you have to convert the source voltage into a current.   This is easily done by putting a resistor between the source and the non-inverting input.  If your signal source is low impedance, then the circuit shown will have distroyed the '3900's inputs.

Your schematics do not show power connections.  The inverter schematic will also not work with dual supplies if the + input input grounded, because that is applying a voltage to the input, which, again, the 3900 doesn't tolerate.   Basically the - input must always be Vbe above the negative supply rail (which should be ground, see next paragraph) and the + input will be between 0 and Vbe above the negative supply rail.  Pulling the + input to Vee (again, normally ground) disables it.  Pulling the - input to Vee (ground) will cause the output to saturate positive.  So if the '3900 is connected to a single supply, then the inverting amp drawn will work OK, but only for negative signals. The grounded + input is not providing a reference for the input signal as in a normal op-amp, but it is simply disabled.  Normally you'd tie the + input to Vcc via a resistor of twice the value of the feedback resistor, and this would bias the output to mid supply.

The 3900 *can* be used with dual supplies, but only if you are a masochist.   The 3900 really shines when used with a single supply.  That was the thing that drove it's design.  You can bias the output above ground with only a single resistor added.    You can also make true non-inverting (or even differencing) integrators and differentiators, so you can still handle positive, ground referenced signals without needing to swing the output negative.

If you are careful to reference all DC signals to Vcc/2 rather than ground, you can certainly use the inverting configurations for DC signal conditioning.   Usually, though, a '3900 would be used as a capacitively coupled AC-only amplifier to avoid the hassle of non ground referenced signals.

Once you wrap your head around how a '3900 works, it may become your favorite amplifier in single supply applications.  If this interests you, then you should read and re-read the following application note until you understand the operation of every circuit int there.

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa653/snoa653.pdf?ts=1694918418784

The above application note contains the vast majority of circuits that you can use the '3900 for.   You pretty much can't use any circuits meant for normal op amps...not without serious modifications anyway.